# Construction of morphisms for Right Derived functors

Tags: category-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, derived-functors

Consider a left exact functor $F: \mathcal{A}\to \mathcal{B}$. According to the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_functor the right derived functors $R^iF$ of $F$ are defined as follows. For an object $A$ in $\mathcal{A}$, one considers an injective resolution $0\to A\to I_0 \to I_1 \to I_2\cdots .$ Applying the functor $F$ to the above and "chopping off $A$" gives $0\to F(I_0)\to F(I_1) \to F(I_2)\to \cdots.$ Then $R^iF(A)$ is the $i$-th cohomology group of the above complex. Now if $R^iF$ is a functor, for every morphism $\phi:A\to A'$ in $\mathcal{A}$ there should exist a morphism $R^iF(\phi):R^iF(A)\to R^iF(A')$. My question is how to construct the morphisms $R^iF(\phi)$?

---

After spending some time with it I think I have an answer. But I am not confident enough to put it as an answer in case there are some loopholes. So, I am posting it here as an edit.

In order to show that there exist maps $R^iF(\phi): R^iF(A)\to R^iF(B)$, we have to show that there exists a map between the complexes $A_\bullet\to B_\bullet$ as shown by the following commutative diagram:
$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{llllllllllll}
0 &\to & A & \ra{i} & I_0 & \ra{d_0} & I_1 & \ra{d_1} & I_2 & \ra{d_2} & \cdots \\
\da{0} & & \da{\phi} & & \da{\psi_0} & & \da{\psi_1} & & \da{\psi_2} & & \da{\psi_n} \\
0 & \to & B & \ra{i'} & I_0' & \ra{d_0'} & I_1' & \ra{d_1'} & I_2' & \ra{d_2'} & \cdots \\
\end{array}
$$
Our goal is to construct the maps $\psi_n$. Construction of $\psi_0$ is easy; we basically lift the map $i'.\phi$ to a map $\psi_0: I_0 \to I_0'$ which is possible since $I_0'$ is injective. Before proceeding further let's show the following fact:

**If $a_0\in image(i)\subset I_0$ then $\psi_0(a_0)\in image(i')$.**

Proof: Let $a_0\in image(i)$ $\implies$ there exists an $a\in A$ such that $i(a)=a_0$. This implies that $ i'.\phi(a)=\psi_0(a_0)$. Hence $\psi_0(a_0)\in image(i')$.

This also implies that if $a_0\in ker(d_0)$ then $\psi_0(a_0)\in ker(d_0')$.

We now proceed to construct the map $\psi_1: I_1 \to I_1'$. We first construct the map $\psi_1':image(d_0)\to I_1'$ in the following way:

For any $a_1\in image(d_0)$ we choose an $a_0\in I_0$ such that $d_0(a_0)=a_1$ and set $\psi_1'(a_1)=d_0'.\psi_0(a_0)~|~ d_0(a_0)=a_1$. To show that $\psi_1'(a_1)$ is independent of the choice of $a_0 \in I_0$, let's choose the representative $a_0+k_0~(k_0\in ker(d_0))$ instead of $a_0$, so that $\psi'(a_1)=d_0'.\psi_0(a_0+k_0)=d_0'.\psi_0(a_0)+d_0'.\psi_0(k_0)=d_0'.\psi_0(a_0)$, since $\psi_0(k_0)\in ker(d_0')$ as shown above.

Having constructed the map $\psi_1': image(d_0) \to I_1'$, we can extend it to $\psi_1: I_1 \to I_1'$ since $I_1'$ is again injective. We can now construct all the maps $\psi_n$ recursively following the same procedure.

If anyone can check and let me know whether the above construction is correct or there are some loopholes in it, that will be very helpful.

Comment: The basic idea is to start with an injective resolution of $A$, then construct a compatible injective resolution of $A'$ recursively by choosing an injective containing the pushout of $I_n \to I_{n+1}$ and $I_n \to I_n'$ and setting that to $I_{n+1}'$.  That then gives a cochain morphism of corresponding injective resolutions, which induces the morphisms you ask about.  You should be able to find more details in most texts treating the subject.  (Posting as a comment in the likely case this is a duplicate.)

Comment: Check out Comparison Theorem 2.3.7 of Weibel's *An Introduction to Homological Algebra*. Essentially, it says that a map $f \colon M \to N$ lifts to a map $f \colon I_\bullet \to J_\bullet$ between injective resolutions, which is unique up to chain homotopy. This ambiguity, if you will, is resolved when taking cohomology. Thus the map $R^i F A \to R^i F A'$ is well defined (of course, all of this assumes that your category has enough injectives to begin with, and possible some other hypothesis that I am forgetting).

Comment: I looked at the book by Weibel where the theorem you mentioned is stated. But I didn't find any proof of this in the book. Is the theorem easy to prove?